# Can't dismiss viewController using parentViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to dismiss a view controller like so:

```
func cropViewController(cropViewController: TOCropViewController!, didFinishCancelled cancelled: Bool) {

        if let vc = cropViewController.parentViewController {
            print("has controller")
            vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

TOCropViewController is a subclass of UIViewController. Sometimes I present it from `self` and sometimes from `picker` (a UIImagePicker controller). I'm trying to dismiss it by accessing the parent however none of the code in the if statement is executing. It can't seem to find the controller. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Any help would be really appreciated! thanks!

Comment: If you are really presenting the TOCropViewController (i.e. `presentViewController` or a present / modal segue) then your code makes no sense, as a presented view controller has no `parentViewController`.

Comment: @matt oh man. My bad. For some reason I thought you had to dismiss from the parent not the currently active VC. Long day. Sorry, and thanks.

Comment: I repeat: there is no such thing as a presented view controller's "parent".

Answer (score 4):

A presented view controller doesn't have a parent, it has a presenter. This can be confusing.

You can send [`dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/instm/UIViewController/c:objc(cs)UIViewController(im)dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) to the presented view controller to have it dismiss itself:

> If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal.

Or you can ask the view controller for its presenting view controller, and ask the presenter to dismiss the presented:

```
    if let vc = cropViewController.presentingViewController {
        print("has presenter")
        vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```